# Word for someone who receives commission

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes someone who receives commission for something? I am not only referring to a salesman but also to for example VISA that charges 3% commission on credit card sales.

Comment: There is another sense of receiving a commission. It means to sit on a special committee created for a particular purpose, in which case the person who gets that sort of commission is called a *commissioner*.  I wouldn’t use it for the tip sense, though.

Comment: Or, of course, an officer cadet receives a commission when he becomes an officer. I can't see any real possibility of confusion between the senses, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An *agent* is the usual term for somebody who takes a commission.  Though the bank is an intermediary between the customer and the shop, it is probably,in legal terms, acting for the customer in the transaction, and so can be called his agent. (IANAL)

Comment: NOAD: "**3** an amount of money, typically a set percentage of the value involved, paid to *an agent* in a commercial transaction" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is *Merchant*

The *merchant* took a 3% cut on each transaction.

Comment: But in the OP's example, VISA receive a commission _from_ the merchant

Comment: They took commission from the transaction for enabling the transaction to happen. Don't VISA receive the commission from the seller and the buyers interactions?

Comment: Yeah, but VISA aren't the merchant, they're a payment intermediary. The _merchant_ here would be the seller.

Comment: This makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use *beneficiary* here, but it obviously won't pick out only people who receive a commission.